# Android ImageButton: image with tranparent background

Tags: android

i want to write an application where the user can change the color scheme. I have Imagebuttons and the images on the buttons are pngs and have transparent background. but when i place them on the buttons they are not transparent anymore. could anybody help me with some code?
thanks!
Anne

Answer (score 4):

Are you ensuring that `android:background="@null"` is set? Otherwise you'll have the gray button background. For example:

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_transparent_png"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

write your layout for `ImageButton` as:

```
<ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:id="@+id/your_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Hope this helps!